# Laundry drains overflows during laundry, but handles full blast hose

Tags: plumbing, drain

The drain for my laundry machine overflows fairly quickly and spills water out whenever I do laundry.

If I put a hose in the drain, and turn it on full blast, it can keep running without it ever overflowing.

What could possibly cause this???

Comment: Let's say you hose will deliver 10 Galons per minute. The washing machine will dump 20 Gallons per minute. Your drain is clogged !

Comment: hmm, i suppose that's probably simply it. didn't look like that high a rate of flow but didn't exactly measure it. i've tried a hose bladder, snaking it, draino, and lye and i can't seem to unclog it.

Answer (score 5):

Your washer pumps faster than your hose flows "full blast."

Simple as that, really. Washer pumps tend to put out a very high gallon-per minute rate when they start emptying the tub. It's a nice large diameter short hose and a short way to pump.

A garden-type hose is limited by the valve it's supplied from, and friction along the length of the hose.

Answer (score 2):

Your garden hose is 1/2 or 5/8 in size.

If you try to fill up a 10 gallon bucket it will take about 2 minutes.

Your washer hose and the drain are 1.5 inch. It will try dump 20 Gallons in a minute. If you have HE (high efficiency) washer, that one uses only 7 Gallons per load.

Your drain is partially clogged.

Answer (score 1):

The chemicals are easy, but they can be hard on plumbing and they can be too dilute by the time they reach the actual blockage to be of much use.

If you've tried snaking the drain, then either you only partially cleared the blockage or you didn't reach the blockage in the first place.

Try heading to a local tool rental store and pick up a commercial grade snake. 100 feet of snake will, most likely, get you all the way to the city sewer (or your septic system), and ensure that you've completely cleared the blockage. Also, be sure to get a head that will fit in your pipes. You may need to rent a couple of different sizes, as your sink drain may only be 1.5", but your main drain out of the house may be a 3" or 4" line. If you run the 1.5" head down the 3" main line, you won't clear much of the clog or could miss it completely.

Now, having somewhat trashed chemical intervention in my opening paragraph...
We had roots growing into our sewer line in the back yard. After having snaked it twice in two winters with a rental machine (and pulling out roots both times), we ended up buying a root killer product and flushing it down the toilet (as directed). We went through 2 bottles of it, following the recommended application instructions and frequency. We haven't had any issues since.